# Xamarin form : Couldn't retrive SSH Fingerprint please ensure the host is reachable and remote login is enabled issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

i was try to connect my virtual mac system to visual studio with pair to Mac features but i am getting error message **Couldn't retrive SSH Fingerprint please ensure the host is reachable and remote login is enabled**

my settings are illustrated below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeZpR.jpg)

[image]

security privacy setting
  enable  remove login
  and also i installed visual studio stable version,Xcode in MAC
  network connection 
[image]

where i am doing wrong , can any one guide me please 
i am getting this both, system are run on same network as well
[image]

even Mac virtual system IP not ping with my windows machine

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Mac OS license agreement forbids you to run it virtually.

Comment: what can i do ? to avoid this or run simulator with visual studio

Comment: The only thing is to buy a Mac or subscribe to a service like macincloud.com. Anyway, check the VirtualBox settings. Something might be blocking you there

Comment: I think this link is helpful https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bd75a7ce-50a5-42ba-946e-15d7dd0a89ad/could-not-retrieve-ssh-fingerprint-make-sure-that-mac-is-reachable-and-remote-login-is-enabled